# From where can I pop up my ClassDiagram Toolbox?

Tags: visual-studio, class, oop, visual-studio-2013, diagram

While I was working around my class diagram in Visual studio 2013, I closed my Toolbox menu. Someone can tell me from where can I pop it up again? Thank you.

Comment: The shortcut is ALT+X.

Answer (score 0):

To open the Toolbox, click Toolbox on the View menu.